# Relation between distribution and $L^p$

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm reading Functional Analysis by Rudin.

We know that every $L^{p},\ 1\leq p \leq\infty$ function can be understood as a (tempered) distribution. (Ah, we're in $\mathbb{R}^n$)
We also know that the dual of $L^{p}$ is isometric to $L^{q}$ unless $p=\infty$.

My question is: for $1\leq p < \infty$ and its conjugate $q$, and $\Lambda\in\mathcal{D}'$, assume $$\sup_{\phi\in\mathcal{D},||\phi||_q\leq1}|\Lambda(q)|<\infty.$$ Can we say that $\Lambda\in L^p$? (i.e. $\exists f\in L^p$ s.t. $f(\phi)=\Lambda(\phi)$ for all $\phi\in\mathcal{D}$.)

If the answer is affirmative, please let me know the proof. External links or PDF files are also welcome.

Thanks!

(p.s. This is my first question in this website. Any comments or tips are appreciated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. To show it, consider a smooth function $\psi$ which is supported in $B(0,1)$, it is positive and has integral $1$, and set $\psi_m(x)=m\psi(mx)$. Consider now the convolutions $\Lambda*\psi_m$, which are functions, and note that, for any $\phi\in\mathcal{D}$ with $\|\phi\|_q\leq 1$, $$\left|\int_{\mathbb R^n}(\Lambda*\psi_m)\cdot\phi\right|=|\Lambda(\tilde{\psi}_m*\phi)|\leq  M,$$ where $M$ is the supremum in your question, and where $\tilde{\psi}$ is the reflection $\tilde{\psi}_m(x)=\psi_m(-x)$, since $\|\tilde{\psi}_m*\phi\|_q\leq 1$.

Suppose now that $p>1$. Then $q<\infty$, therefore $\mathcal{D}$ is dense in $L^q$, and this shows that $$\left|\int_{\mathbb R^n}(\Lambda*\psi_m)\cdot f\right|\leq M$$ for all $f\in L^q$ with $\|f\|_q\leq 1$. Therefore, $(\Lambda*\psi_m)$ is a bounded sequence in $L^p$, hence a subsequence of it converges weakly to a function $f\in L^p$. But, $\Lambda*\psi_m$ converges to $\Lambda$ in the space of distributions, therefore $\Lambda$ can be identified with $f$, which is an $L^p$ function.

If, now $p=1$, then we obtain that $$\left|\int_{\mathbb R^n}(\Lambda*\psi_m)\cdot f\right|\leq M$$ for all $f\in C_0(\mathbb R^n)$ (continuous functions that vanish at $\infty$). Therefore $\Lambda*\psi_m$ is a bounded Borel measure on $\mathbb R^n$, with total variation bounded by $M$. Since a subsequence of $(\Lambda*\psi_m)$ converges weakly in the space of Borel measures, we deduce that $\Lambda$ can be identified with a bounded Borel measure.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I have a question for the equality $$\left|\int_{\mathbb R^n}(\Lambda*\psi_m)\cdot\phi\right|=|\Lambda(\tilde{\psi_m}*\phi)|.$$ Is it true for $\Lambda\in\mathcal{D}'$, $\psi\in\mathcal{D}$, $\phi\in L^q$ that $$(\Lambda\ast\psi)\ast\phi=\Lambda\ast(\psi\ast\phi)$$ including well-definedness?

Comment: I edited my answer; it can be done by only considering the distribution defined on functions in $\mathcal{D}$.

Comment: Oh, very nice! I want to point out two things:
1. In order to use the fact that $\mathcal{D}$ is dense in $L^{q}$, we must have $1\leq q< \infty$. So, the range of $p$ must be changed into $1 < p \leq \infty$ Is this right? 
2. Since we only know that $\Lambda\ast\psi_m$ is a linear functional on $\mathcal{D}$ which is bounded by $L^q$-norm, I think that we must use Hahn-Banach theorem to say that $\Lambda\ast\psi_m \in (L^q)^{\ast}$ Then, use denseness of $\mathcal{D}$ to conclude that the extension is unique and $\Lambda\ast\psi_m \in L^p$

Comment: I re-edited my answer to cover your first point. For your second point, $\Lambda*\psi_m$ is actually a function, it is not just a distribution. It also has good enough decay at $\infty$ (it is bounded by $N(1+|x|)^{-k}$, for some $k\in\mathbb N$), and this may have to be used somewhere in the proof.