# Tempered distribution in Sobolev sapce

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ and $u \in \mathcal S'(\mathbb R^n)$, where $\mathcal S'$ denote the tempered distribution space. I want to show that if
$$
u - \Delta u = f \ \text{ in }\ \mathcal S',
$$
then $u \in H^2(\mathbb R^n)$, which means,
$$
\| (1+|\xi|^2) \hat u(\xi)\|_{L^2} = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \big| (1+|\xi|^2) \hat u(\xi) \big|^2 d\xi < \infty.
$$
I have shown that $\mathcal F[(1+|\xi|^2) \varphi(x)] = (1-\Delta)\hat\varphi$ for any $\varphi \in \mathcal S$. Thus
$$
\langle (1+|\xi|^2) \hat u, \varphi \rangle = \langle \mathcal F[(1-\Delta) u], \varphi \rangle = \langle \hat f, \varphi \rangle, \quad \forall \varphi \in \mathcal S.
$$
But I have no idea how to show the rest.

If, at least, $\hat u$ is a locally integrable function, we can conclude that $\| (1+|\xi|^2) \hat u(\xi)\|_{L^2} = \| \hat f \|_{L^2} < \infty$, since $(1+|\xi|^2) \hat u(\xi) = \hat f$ a.e. by the fundamental lemma of calculus of variations. But for $u$ that is a tempered distribution, how to deal with it?

Comment: Have you ever heard about Schwarz representation theorem ? See [here](https://math.mit.edu/~rbm/iml/Chapter1.pdf) Theorem 1.1 for a weaker version.

Comment: $(1+|\xi|^2)\hat{u}=\hat{f}$ is in $L^2$ so you are done $u\in H^2$. Also $\hat{u}=\frac{\hat{f}}{1+|\xi|^2)} \in L^2$ so $u\in L^2\subset L^1_{loc}$.

Comment: @Falcon No, I haven't.

Comment: @reuns Sine now we only know that $(1+|\xi|^2)\hat u = \hat f$ in $\mathcal S'$, how to show $(1+|\xi|^2)\hat u = \hat f$ in $L^2$ (equal almost everywhere)?

Comment: $\hat{u}=\frac{\hat{f}}{1+|\xi|^2}$ in $S'$ so the distribution $\hat{u}$ is represented by a $L^2$ function, so $u$ is represented by a $L^2$ function. ie. $\forall \phi \in S,<u,\phi>$ is given by integrating $\phi$ against the $L^2$ function $\mathcal{F}^{-1}[\frac{\hat{f}}{1+|\xi|^2}]$. That we can obviously write as $u=\mathcal{F}^{-1}[\frac{\hat{f}}{1+|\xi|^2}]$. What do you expect more?

Comment: @reuns What do you mean "represented by a $L^2$ function"? $((1 + |\xi|^2)\hat u, \varphi) = (\hat f, \varphi)$ holds for any $\varphi \in \mathcal S$.  But since neither $(1 + |\xi|^2)\hat u$ nor $\hat f$ is in $\mathcal S$, it's not trivial that $\|(1 + |\xi|^2)\hat u\|_{L^2} = \|\hat f\|_{L^2}$. How do you prove it?

Comment: $<\hat{u},\phi>=<\frac{\hat{f}}{1+|\xi|^2},\phi>$ for all $\phi \in S$. Again what do you expect more?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a smooth function $\psi$ which is supported in $B(0,1)$, it is positive and has integral $1$, and set $\psi_m(x)=m\psi(mx)$. Consider now the convolutions to two sides of the equation,
$$
u_m -\Delta u_m = f_m,
$$
where $u_m = u*\psi_m$, and $f_m = f*\psi_m$. We have
$$
f_m \to f, \qquad \text{in $L^2$ and in $\mathcal{S}'$}
$$
and
$$
u_m \to u, \qquad \text{in $\mathcal{S}'$}.
$$
Since $\|u_m\|_{H^2} \le \|f_m\| \le C(\|f\| + 1)$, we have $u_m \to u$ in $L^2$, and in $H^2$ weakly. (If necessary, we choose a subsequence of $\{m\}$.)

The problem is similar as the following answer.

[Relation between distribution and $L^p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1516928/relation-between-distribution-and-lp)